# Unhandled - error Encountered an unhandled error in this Studio. Error When I started the Sanity Start. I got this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sanity

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'jsonType')
> at validateNonObjectFieldsProp (/static/js/app.bundle.js:170029:16)
> at _default (/static/js/app.bundle.js:169997:155)
> at visitors.reduce._objectSpread._problems (/static/js/app.bundle.js:168504:17)
> at Array.reduce ()
> at /static/js/app.bundle.js:168503:21
> at /static/js/app.bundle.js:168522:70
> at /static/js/app.bundle.js:168638:12
> at /static/js/app.bundle.js:168653:95
> at Array.forEach ()
> at traverseSchema (/static/js/app.bundle.js:168652:9)

Answer (score 2):

You may have specified a `type` in your schema that you intended to be a title or name. For example:

```
{
  type: 'string',
  name: 'title',
  type: 'Title'  //  <-- In this example, this should be title: 'Title'
}
```